# Write Custom Authentication classes for ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

The out of the box ASP.NET 5 Identity classes are straight forward and it is easy to setup and use, my problem however is that I'm working with a legacy system with existing user and permission tables that I have to customize the Identity system for. The Identity system seems very pluggable, but I can't find any proper documentation on how to write custom Identity classes. Is there any documentation on

1. How to write custom ASP.NET 5 Identity classes that can cater for legacy system user and permission tables
2. How do I setup the use of the custom Identity classes for use in a ASP.NET 5, MVC 6 application?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.asp.net/identity. There are some samples of custom identity implementation there. It is about current (MVC 5) version, but things concerned ASP.Net Identity has changed not so much in ASP.vNext.

Comment: Thank you @AndyKorneyev, I will have a look

Answer (score 3):

There is not a lot of documentation available yet, so I played around with the latest Identity classes which is currently `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 3.0.0-rc1-final` and came up with a solution that is working with my legacy user database tables.

First of all make sure that your legacy user entity class implement the `IdentityUser` class so that we can use the class for authentication within ASP.NET 5

```
public class MyLegacyUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Your MyLegacyUser properties will go here as usual
}
```

Make sure that you ignore any properties inherited from the `IdentityUser` class that you would not like to use (Those are the properties not contained within your user table). We do this by using the fluent api within the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DbContext` class.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyLegacyUser> MyLegacyUser { get; set; }

    // For simplicity I will add only the OnModelCreating method here
    protected override void OnModelCreating
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyLegacyUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Ignore(e => e.AccessFailedCount);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.Claims);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.Email);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.EmailConfirmed);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.Id);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.LockoutEnabled);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.LockoutEnd);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.Logins);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.NormalizedEmail);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.NormalizedUserName);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.PasswordHash);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.PhoneNumber);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.Roles);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.SecurityStamp);
            entity.Ignore(e => e.TwoFactorEnabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have to implement our own custom `UserManager` class to authenticate with our legacy user. Make sure that your new class implement `UserManager<T>`, where `T` is your `MyLegacyUser`. Once this is done override the `CheckPasswordAsync` to authenticate your user.

**Note:** The `CheckPasswordAsync` method is not responsible for returning an authenticated user, it is simply a method that will return true or false to indicate if the user was successfully authenticated. The authenticated user is set by another class which I will explain below.

```
public class MyLegacyUserManager : UserManager<MyLegacyUser>
{
    public WorldUserManager(IUserStore<MasterUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<MasterUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<MasterUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<MasterUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<MasterUser>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger, contextAccessor)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(MasterUser user, string password)
    {
        // This is my own authentication manager class that handles user authentication
       // Add your own code to authenticate your user here
        return new AuthenticationManager().Authenticate(user.EmailAddress, password);
    }
}
```

Once this is done we have to implement our own `UserStore` class. There are a few interfaces you can implement such as `IUserStore<T>`, `IUserLoginStore<T>`, `IUserClaimsStore<T>` etc. I implemented the `IUserClaimsStore<T>` interface and implemented the `GetUserIdAsync`, `GetUserNameAsync`, `FindByIdAsync` and `GetClaimsAsync` methods

```
public class MyLegacyUserClaimStore : IUserClaimStore<MyLegacyUser>
{
    // Here I simply returned the username of the user parameter I recieved as input
    public Task<string> GetUserIdAsync(MasterUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => user.UserName, cancellationToken);
    }
}

// Here I simply returned the username of the user parameter I recieved as input
public Task<string> GetUserNameAsync(MasterUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Run(() => user.UserName, cancellationToken);
}

public Task<MasterUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // This is my manager class to read my user for the userId
    // Add your own code to read the user for the set Id here
    return Task.Run(() => new MyLegacyUserUserManager().ReadForEmailAddress(userId, 0, true, true), cancellationToken);
}

 public Task<MasterUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     // This is my manager class to read my user for the normalizedUserName
    // Add your own code to read the user for the set normalizedUserName here
     return Task.Run(() => new MyLegacyUserManager().ReadForEmailAddress(normalizedUserName, 0, true, true), cancellationToken);
 }

// If you want to make use of Claims make sure that you map them here
// If you do not use claims, consider implementing one of the other IUserStore interfaces 
//such as the IUserLoginStore so that you do not have to implement the GetClaimsAsync method
public async Task<IList<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync(MasterUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();

    foreach (var claim in user.Claims)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(claim.ClaimType, claim.ClaimValue));
    }

    return claims;
}
```

These are all the classes you need for custom authentication. No let's configure our custom authentication method in the `Startup.cs` class. Add the following to the `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     // Use the default role, IdentityRole as we are not implementing roles
     // Add our custom UserManager and UserStore classes
     services.AddIdentity<MyLegacyUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Auth/Login");
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Auth/Login");
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Auth/Login");
        })
        .AddUserManager<MyLegacyUserManager>()
        .AddUserStore<MyLegacyUserUserClaimStore>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
}
```

In the `Configure` method make sure that you specify that you want to use the Identity functionality to authenticate

**Note:** The order of your use statements are important, make sure that you include `UseIdentity` before `UseMvc` if you are using Mvc.

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIdentity();
    // Your useMvc and other use statements will go here
}
```

Now we have configured our custom authentication classes and we can authenticate by using the default `SignInManager` class. Here is an example of my `AuthController` class

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private SignInManager<MyLegacyUserUser> _signInManager;

    public AuthController(SignInManager<MasterUser> signInManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    // For simplicity I will only add the Login action here
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.Username, loginViewModel.Password, true, false);

        if (result == SignInResult.Success)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "SomeControllerToRedirectTo");
        }

        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Auth");
    }
}
```

When your user is authenticated you can access the user claims as you would have done with MVC 5, for example

```
var email = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email)).Value;
```